Temporary upload link led to invalid upload attempt Dropbox error
I was trying to upload files to my dropbox account reading dropbox api documentation.
I got a temporary upload file link when i did the following cURL command
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_temporary_upload_link \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer <Bearer Token> \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \      
    --data "{\"commit_info\":{\"autorename\":true,\"mode\":\"add\",\"mute\":false,\"path\":\"/dog.jpg\",\"strict_conflict\":false},\"duration\":3600}"                                                                                                     

The response was like this
{"link": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/apitul/1/dfkjeijaf"}

where "dfkjeijaf"  is a code i replaced for showing publicly here.  I tried to upload files to this url through postman, for this i set content-type application/octet-stream
and passed a file in the request body as binary. but i am getting an  error response with
status code 409 and response body as "Temporary upload link led to invalid upload attempt". what i am doing wrong?

Based on the error message, "Temporary upload link led to invalid upload attempt”, this issue can be caused by an invalid parameter value that you are using with the get_temporary_upload_link endpoint. For example, this can occur if the path supplied to the get_temporary_upload_link to generate the link is invalid. That said, I tested the cURL command you provided and successfully generated a temporary upload link and uploaded a file.
May I ask if you have provided the exact get_temporary_upload_link parameters and values from the cURL command that caused the issue?
Please bear in mind that another option for uploading files with the Dropbox API is to use the /2/files/upload or /2/files/upload_session/start endpoint.
In order to upload large files, larger than 150 MB, using the Dropbox API, you should use the "upload sessions" feature. This allows you to upload a large file by sending multiple requests, each with one portion of the file.

i think there is no problem with temporary upload link, because when i accidentally use this link without passing a file in the request body the response was 200 ok, and an empty file was created in dropbox. but when i pass a file in the request body i am getting Temporary upload link led to invalid upload attempt.

If you are still encountering the same error while attempting to upload the file, can you provide the exact parameter values that you are using and how you are passing the file to the temporary upload link?

It was due to my dropbox account trial expired.it is currently working.
